# Properly configure TrigramSimilarity and SearchVector for searching users

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

I have written a search function in order to do FTS on my user model however, I am having a hard time figuring out how to configure it in order to get similar results as well, for instance, if the username contains **MOST** character of the search query it should display it as well. for instance if I search for `bob` and there is a user with username `bobuser13` it should be displayed as well.

Currently, my search function is:

```
def search(self, search_text):
    search_vectors = ( 
          SearchVector(
              'username', weight='A', config='english'
            ) + SearchVector(
              'last_name' , weight='B', config='english'
            ) + SearchVector(
              'first_name' , weight='C', config='english'
            )+ SearchVector(
              'first_name','last_name', weight='D', config='english'
            ) + + SearchVector(
              'bio', weight='D', config='english'
            )
          )
    search_query = SearchQuery(
        search_text, config=' english'
    )
    search_rank = SearchRank(search_vectors,search_query)
    
    trigram = TrigramSimilarity(
        'username', search_text
    ) + TrigramSimilarity(
        'last_name',search_text
    ) + TrigramSimilarity(
        'first_name',search_text
    ) 
    qs = (
        self.get_queryset()
        .filter(sv=search_query)
        .annotate(rank=search_rank, trigram=trigram, bs=Greatest('rank','trigram'))
        .filter(Q(bs__gte=0.1))
        .order_by('-bs')
    )
    
    return qs
```

And my user model is:

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField()
    sv = pg_search.SearchVectorField(null=True)
    
    objects = ProfileManager()
    
    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            GinIndex(fields=['sv'],name='search_idx_user'),
        ]
    
def __str__(self):
    return self.username

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "{}".format(self.slug)
```

how can I configure this so that it also includes similar names as well?

Comment: What query is this generating and sending to the server?  You are unlikely to get good performance through a single query.  I'd question the use of FTS to start with, it is more for sentences, not for single proper nouns.  What if you just use trigram?

Comment: for instance if I query “Bob”. You are suggesting if the query is a single term I should only use trigram? So I have to check if the search query is more than 1 word? Or can I use icontains? @jjanes

Comment: english FTS config doesn't know what to do with "Bob", "Robert", "Robbie", "Bobbie", etc., or "Jim", "James", "Jamie", or "Chuck", "Charles", "Chaz".  Maybe there is some other config that does know how to standardize them. But in the absence of such domain specific standardization, I don't see much point in using FTS on name fields, and much less on username fields.  Rather than detecting the query being one word or two, maybe ask if they want to search for people's names, versus computer login account names?

Comment: My intention is to have one search field that search everything and they can see all the objects in the app such as posts and users. Thats why I don’t know if I should configure different search functions that will query based on the word.

Comment: You cannot do similarity search with PostgreSQL full text search. Try the `pg_trgm` extension.